# click angularjs button with javascript and element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, click

I am working on a browser extension that will automatically click a button on a page. The code works on every site except ones with angularjs.

The following code is my attempt at clicking an angularjs button and have it register the click, but it does not work.

```
//applyButton is the button element.
if(angular) {
     var e = angular.element(applyButton);
     e.trigger('click');
     e.scope().$apply();
 } else {
     applyButton.click();
 }
```

Here is the angular html code for the applyButton that is not registering the "click"

```
<input value="Apply" class="apply button gift-card-apply" data-ng-click="!orderSubmitErrors.giftCard.sectionHasErrors &amp;&amp; applyGiftCard($event)" client-validation="onSubmit,giftCard,validateSubsection" type="button">
```

Is there a best practice to click buttons and change input fields for angularjs from javascript if I only have access to the document.element for those items?

Comment: does element exist when your code runs? Can't use conventional page load handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to wrap your element in a [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to invoke a `.click` on your element. Observe the following simplified example...

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button id="btn" ng-click="click()">click</button>
</div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.click = function() {
        console.log('click');
    }

    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('btn')).trigger('click')
    });

    //does not work
    angular.element(document.getElementById('btn')).trigger('click')
});
```

With this, you will not be needing to call `e.scope().$apply();` - `$timeout` will invoke a cycle if necessary. Additionally, while you didn't specify in your example, its worth nothing that [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) requires jQuery and is not baked into AngularJS's jqLite.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/c70q4fwa/) - demo

Comment: Thanks for the code example, for some reason I can't get past $timeout...it hangs when it sees it. But if(angular) is true. Also the jsfiddle seems to not be loading angular maybe jsfiddle is down.

Comment: are you injecting `$timeout` into your controller? The fiddle seems to be working could you try again?

Comment: example works in chrome but not firefox for some reason on jsfiddle. So I can see it working now. Thanks for the example. I understand how it is working now after playing with it.